# How demote multiple site links or prevent Google adding any of a page type?

Tags: google, google-search-console, sitelinks

I have a website with lot of member profile pages such as:

```
/profile-1.html
/profile-2.html
/profile-3.html
/profile-4.html
...
```

How can I tell Google not add these profiles in site links?  There are too many to demote one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure there is a way to demote multiple links in Google Webmaster Tools currently. However, there are other methods of achieving the result. I am assuming you have a sitemap for the website? If so I would go change the `<priority>0.1</priority>`. Doing this helps determine which url to show if multiple pages from a website match a query. My only other suggestion is to place the profile pages into a directory and using either the .htaccess or robots.txt to prevent robots from crawling them.

```
<url>
  <loc>http://example.com/profile-1.html</loc>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
  <priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
```